# Telegram bot PHP Inline button

Tags: php, telegram-bot, inline

подскажите пожалуйста как на inline кнопки отобразить данные из БД mysql ?
мне нужно если при нажатии на кнопку бот отвечает inline кнопками списком контрагентов вот этой функции

```
function table_kontragent_sale($connect){
$i = 0 ;
$query = "SELECT `ID`, `Name`, `Token`
          FROM `kontragent`
          WHERE `TypeID`='1' AND `Active`='1'
          ORDER BY `Name`";
    $result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);
    if(!$result)
        die(mysqli_error($connect));
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $rowKontr[$i] = $row;
            ++$i;
      }
    return($rowKontr);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

сделал таким образом все получилось, если кому надо вот код

```
if($message == "продажа"){
                     $method = 'sendMessage';
                        $send_data = [
                                        'text'   => 'Выберите контрагента',
                                        'reply_markup' => [
                                            'inline_keyboard' => [
                                                  [
                                                      [
                                                        'text' => 'Кнопка 1',
                                                        'callback_data' => 'test'
                                                      ]
                                                   ]
                                              ]
                                          ]
                                      ];
    
              $j = 0;
              $g = 0;
                    for ($i = 0; $i < count($array); ++$i) {
                        if ($g == 2) { $g = 0; ++$j;}
                        $send_data['reply_markup']['inline_keyboard'][$j][$g]['text'] = $array[$i]['Name'];
                        $send_data['reply_markup']['inline_keyboard'][$j][$g]['callback_data'] = $array[$i]['Name'];
                  ++$g;
              }
           }
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]